# Input map Error while creating a Backend resource in APIM through C# using Pulumi

Tags: c#, azure, pulumi, apim

This is the sample code provided in pulumi documentation however this does throw an compilation error.
https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/apimanagement/backend/

[compilation error in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9A5G.png)

Please let me know any idea to resolve or help me to provide a sample code through which i can create a Backend resource in APIM which can connect to the Named value in Headers.

[Sample Backend Resource in Azure APIM through GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d87Dp.png)

[Refer to this picture about my comment of adding the named value in the Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIByL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The example are automatically generated and it looks like the generator didn't handle the type initialization correctly. Here is one way to fix it (replace the relevant lines):

```
Header = 
{
    {
        "x-my-1", new[] { "val1", "val2" }.ToImmutableArray()
    },
},
Query = 
{
    {
        "sv", new[] { "xx", "bb", "cc" }.ToImmutableArray()
    },
},
```

Comment: Hi @Mikhail

Thanks, this did work.
This will attach the Manual value in the Headers.

If i want to attach the Named Value , can you please share a sample of code.

Uploaded the picture in the main description for reference.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too deep on that part of API management. Isn't that what https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/apimanagement/namedvalue/ is for?

Comment: No worries @Mikhail.
The link that you shared is for creating the Named Value.
And that named value can be used in the Header of the Backend.

Trying to find a sample piece of code.

However your code snippet did helped a lot.
Thanks again.